# Plotting ECDF in R ggplot2, choosing a scale for the Y axis that shows maximum as well as 4-9's, 5-9's, etc

Tags: r, data-visualization, scales, ggplot2, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I regularly make graphs of ECDF for performance latencies, where I want to show an upper bound on latency at P(x) < 0.999, 0.9999, etc. As such, I usually scale the Y axis logarithmically to separate values very close to 1. However, I realized that my scale has the problem that the value 1 itself ends up off-the-graph which means I can't also show maximum latency on the same graph.

[image]

obtained as follows

```
  tn <- trans_new("rareevents",
                  function(x) -(log10(1+-x)),
                  function(y) -(-1+(10**(-y)))
                  )

  g <- g + scale_y_continuous(trans=tn, limits=c(0,.99995), breaks=c(0,0.5,.9,.99,.999,.9999), labels=c(0,0.5,.9,.99,.999,.9999))
```

Is there a standard scale I should be using for this purpose?